# Cannot connect to Hiveserver2 on http mode

Tags: hive, mode, transport

I am planning to apply Knox to our HDP 2.2 cluster but I encountered the  hiveserver2 http mode connection. I configured hive-site.xml like below:

```
    <property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.file.impl.disable.cache</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>hive.server2.allow.user.substitution</name>
     <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
    <value>cliservice</value>
    <description>Path component of URL endpoint when in HTTP mode.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
    <value>http</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
    <value>10010</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.min.worker.threads</name>
    <value>5</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.max.worker.threads</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>
```

However, when I try to connect to the server via beeline, the beeline hangs. There is no exception and error messages in the log file. If I change the transport mode to "biniary", the problem is totally gone. I don't know why it happens.

What should I do for that?